# Don't update all textfields to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uitextfield

I have three `textFields` and when the user enters information into them, the information is sent to `Firebase`.

```
     func buttonMethod() { 
if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid{
            if let City = City.text{
                if let Major = Major.text{
                    if let College = College.text{

                        let saveObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                            "uid": uid,
                            "City" : City,
                            "Major" : Major,
                            "College" : College
                        ]
                   }
               }
          }
      }



FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).setValue(saveObject)
```

Using those same `textFields`, the user can edit their information. And the information will be displayed in labels in another view controller.

```
  func loadInfo(){
        if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil{

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    for post in postsDictionary {
                        //self.posts.add(post.value)

                        let city = postsDictionary["City"] as! String
                        let major = postsDictionary["Major"] as! String
                        let college = postsDictionary["College"] as! String
                        self.City.text = city
                        self.Major.text = major
                        self.College.text = college
                    }

                }})}
    }
```

My problem is that when the user edits the information, if a `textField` was not edited it replaces the value of the non-edited `textField` in `Firebase` with an empty string. I want it to be that if the user does not edit a `textField` then the value in `Firebase` should stay the same.I started out with this:

```
 if City.tex t== "" {

 }
 if Major.text=="" {

 }
 if College.text==""{

 }
```

But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: There is no need to loop through the dictionary also when you retrieve this value from firebase is it showing value in `textField`

Comment: sorry no, its showing the value in a label in another view controller @NiravD

Comment: Then why don't you set `textField` text with the firebase data?

Comment: @NiravD I don't really understand your question

Comment: What i'm saying is with `observeSingleEvent` you can retrieve Firebase data and put its value in textField that user updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the textfield text is empty then don't send that field to firebase. Say if user haven't edited city field then don't add city textField in the method to send value to firebase.

Please try update your `buttonMethod()` like this,

```
func buttonMethod() {
    if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid{

        var tempObject = [String:Any]()
        tempObject["uid"] = uid
        if !City.text.isEmpty {
            tempObject["City"] = City.text
        }

        if !Major.text.isEmpty{
            tempObject["Major"] = Major.text
        }

        if !College.text.isEmpty{
            tempObject["College"] = College.text
        }

        let saveObject:Dictionary<String,Any> = tempObject

}
```

Instead of saving the object to firebase update the data at firebase using `updateChildValues()` function

Comment: I understand that logic and that was my thought process too, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Could you please share the method that you use to send these values to firebase

Comment: It's the first chuck of code, I included in the question

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please try out as above and confirm?

Comment: it doesn't work, when I edit one text field then the other values get deleted from firebase as opposed to before when the values where just empty strings

Comment: Ok then is there a way to get the current values in firebase when you are in the viewcontroller which contains these text field.

Comment: Then try instead of saving the data try updating the data at firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another solution: you could show the original values/information on your text fields instead of leaving them blank. So try to remove the textfields in your code with the following structure:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldWithDefaultValue: View {

    var model:userModel    // Replace it with your own view model
    var textFieldName: String
    @State var editedValue: String

    init(model: userModel, text: String) {
        self.model = model
        self.textFieldName = text
        switch self.textFieldName {
        case "Name": self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model.getName())
        case "Bio": self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model.getBio())
        case "Interest": self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model.getInterest())
        default:
            self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: "No records")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(textFieldName, text: $editedValue)
    }

}
```